# My android studio 4.3 app is crashing right away and I get exception

Tags: android

The IDE switches to Debug window and it lists an exception. I cannot figure out how to copy or save the entire window to show you. The final list entry is "stat: 130. forwardingOs (libcore.io)". Is there a way to copy the entire message list so I can present it to you? I am guessing that this exception is related to the new android studio 4.3 I downloaded. I placed a break in onCreate of my class but it never reaches it. My manifest is below and I assume the exception is UI related.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.curco.rsproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
            android:name=".MyPrefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".MyPrefs" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: there is a save icon on log tool

Comment: try again to save your log and post it here. otherwise, nobody can help you